# ACR.UserDialogs Splat - Could not be resolved as it was built against Version=v5.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm not able to build my project When I upgraded my version of Visual Studio 2019 to the latest.

I'm using `Splat 2.0.0` as I am user `ACR.UserDialogs` 6.5.1 as part of a shared project.

I got the following error message:

> .nuget/packages/splat/2.0.0/lib/netstandard1.1/Splat.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETPortable,Version=v5.0" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111".

My installed packages:

- Xamarin.Mac Version: 5.10.0.153 (Visual Studio Community)
- Xamarin.iOS Version: 12.10.0.153 (Visual Studio Community)
- Xamarin Designer Version: 16.1.0.464
- Xamarin.Android
- Version: 9.3.0.22 (Visual Studio Community)

Comment: it's related to the Mono Framework version that this particular version of VS is forcing.Please try to downgrade to VS 2017 to try to make it work.

Comment: Well, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to the Mono Framework version that this particular version of VS is forcing.

Please downgrade to 8.3.11 and install the minimum required version of mono for that and it will work.

Here's the link to VS:
https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/be7eb138-bef6-460b-90c6-dacd3de18266/18dac98baf9b79fbba45016f59c0e0b0/visualstudioformac-8.3.11.1.dmg

and here's the link to mono:
http://download.mono-project.com/archive/6.4.0/macos-10-universal/MonoFramework-MDK-6.4.0.194.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg